# Cross site origin issue when providing a Rest API

Tags: javascript, html, http

I am writing a web-service.
I would like to provide 3rd party websites and api to my server.
I am doing this by providing them with a javascript file that they can include from my server.
Much similarly to what Facebook/Twitter/Google are doing.

The problem is that the Same Origin Policy prohibits them from making calls to my API server. What is the clean and correct way for me to implement my API file + server?

Am I supposed to allow cross-origin-requests on my server from just anyone, or is there something I can put in my JavaScript file instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable CORS you need to add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in your response. This will allow any website to invoke your services (you can restrict the access changing the * with the allowed domain). [This](http://enable-cors.org/) is a good reference

Comment: Thanks. Is this how these things are implemented in facebook/google/twitter?

Comment: Yes, if you open the http watch, open http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js (this is the Google CDN) in the browser and look at the headers you'll see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

Comment: I think I misunderstood... Do I need to allow CORS on all of my REST-API (all of my get requests) . Or only when serving the js file itself (just the request for the js file)?

Comment: Loading a JS from a different domain is fine (that's the base for `JSONP`), you need that header on the API responses